# Proper way to set connection strings in ci during msbuild/deploy

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, msdeploy

I have a CI server (Bamboo, but I don't think that it matters) building and auto-deploying my application. During local development I use localdb (`<connectionStrings>` node in my `web.config`)

```
    <add name="MyApp" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Initial Catalog=MyApp" />
    <add name="MyApp_Patients" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Initial Catalog=AppleHms_MyApp" />
    ...
```

When deployed obviously it shouldn't use this. It should use my deployment sql server connection string.

I know that I can write a web.config transform for this and I even know that I can encrypt the web.config but I'm not sure how the db connection-string is supposed to get in there properly. What makes sense to me is for the CI server to overwrite each connectionString - so my config transform should maybe look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyApp" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="${main-db-connectionstring}"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    <add name="MyApp_Patients" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="${patients-db-connectionstring}"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    ...
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

With the overrides coming from variables in my ci server (presumably some part of msbuild or deploy)?

Is that correct that this is the "right" way of doing this? What exactly do I have to do with msbuild/deploy to make this happen?

Answer (score 6):

We are also using bamboo for CI and deployment, and what we are doing is:

- Packages project containing a default Parameters.xml as the msdeploy parameter declaration file.
- Maintaining SetParameters.xml files for our various environement.
- Packaging projects on nightly build.
- Releasing nightly packages as bamboo artifacts.
- Using msdeploy to apply parametrization over these packages when deploying for a particular nightly build.

Basically the deployment as it concern msdeploy is like as following :

```
msdeploy
  -verb:sync  
  -source:package="NightlyPackage.zip"  
  -dest:iisApp="YourIISHost/YourIISSite"  
  -declareParamFile="YourEnvironementSetParameters.xml"
```

Your Parameters.xml per project package would look like as following:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter
       name="ConnectionString1-Web.config Connection String"  
       description=""  
       defaultValue="localhost">
          <parameterEntry  
             kind="XmlFile"  
             scope="\\web.config$"  
             match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='ConnectionString1']/@connectionString"  
           />
    </parameter>
 </parameters>
```

Where `ConnectionString1` is the name of a connectionString.

And your YourEnvironementSetParameters.xml would look like as following:

```
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="ConnectionString1-Web.config Connection String" value="Your parametrized connection string value " />
</parameters>
```

There are conventions when using parametrization on some fields with webdeploy. Connection strings are concerned, so it's good practice to respect the following parameter naming when it comes to refer to web.config connection strings :

```
%NameOfYourConnectionStringAsInWebConfig%-Web.config Connection String
```

Comment: Thanks Koresh! If parameters are coming out of a file then you are checking a file with passwords in to source control aren't you?

Comment: No, we use SSPI connection strings.

Comment: Thanks for the thoroughness of this answer, particularly the piece about conventions, which I wasn't aware of. Moving to those conventions fixed a deployment problem that was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2):

Using the XMLPoke task would be the proper way to do so via MSBuild script

[XMLPoke on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598687.aspx)

Also to get a really good reference, check [Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi blog](http://sedodream.com/2011/12/29/UpdatingXMLFilesWithMSBuild.aspx), always helpful

Comment: Thanks - can you give an example of what the msdeploy or msbuild command would look like? How would I pass in a value from the command line? My reading of the (nearly worthless) documentation and the (much more helpful) linked blog is that it would have to be stored in the csproj?